# psql hangs right on starting it

Tags: postgresql

I just installed postgres 9.2 on windows 7.  The install went fine.  Opening up pgadmin went fine and I added a database called playorm which worked fine.  I connected with SQL Workbench to the playorm database which worked.

I then start the command line like so

```
 ./psql.exe -h localhost -U postgres playorm
```

It just hangs forever.  5 mintues later and it is still hung.  Am I missing something in the command( I also tried -d playorm instead but still hangs).  Anyone else have 9.2 working on windows 7?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ah, I figured it out.  It ONLY hangs in cygwin....dangit, I hate using DOS command prompts.

Comment: Get msys - the most convenient way these days is via git for windows. It provides a civilized(ish) shell. BTW, you should accept your answer.

Comment: I usually do accept my own answer...in fact just tried now and I have to wait one more day....grrrrrr..stupid stack overflow feature of preventing users from accepting their own answer :(.

Comment: In my cygwin psql works just fine. However, a colleage with similar setup is experiencing your problem. I suspect it has to do with a missing cygwin or postgres module. But it is definitely solvable. If I find how I will update this post. In the meantime you may consider using git bash shell from git installation https://git-scm.com/downloads.

Comment: Many years later but the solution might be to use winpty

Comment: On git-bash on Windows 10 x64, this works: `winpty /c/Program\ Files/PostgreSQL/11/bin/psql -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432`

Comment: Use git bash.  I'm trying to determine the inconsistency between the git bash and the cygwin minttys(?).